# WebKit/Phantomjs why output of getComputedStyles is that way?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, cross-browser, cssom, webidl

on most browsers (e.g. Firefox, Opera) getting the computed Style for a element return a nice object of type `CSSStyleDeclaration`. On Chrome 28 and PhantomJS 1.9 I get an object that starts with numbered keys listing all the CSS properties, and then the properties (in case of Chrome).

For example, in opera:
[image]

In Chrome 28:
[image]

and then eventually you get to the useful part:
[image]

in PhantomJS 1.9 it's even worse, you get the numbered attributes, and then only two named properties: lenght and cssText.

```
...
219: 'glyph-orientation-horizontal',
220: 'glyph-orientation-vertical',
221: '-webkit-svg-shadow',
222: 'vector-effect',
length: 223,
cssText: 'background-attachment: scroll; background-clip: border-box; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); background-image: none; background-o...
```

Answer (score 1):

The object returned in all cases should be a `CSSStyleDeclaration` instance (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration).

The object is only supposed to have the number indexed values and a `length` (making it *array-like*) and `cssText`.

The Chrome implementation adds the *non-standard* named attributes. If you want an simple object of the property/value pairs, you can used the `getPropertyValue` method on the instance. e.g (and most of this code is from the example on MDN)

```
function simpleStyles(node) {
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(node);
  var styleMap = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < style.length; i++) {
    var prop = style[i]; //the numbered props
    var value = style.getPropertyValue(prop); //access the value;
    styleMap[prop] = value;
  }
  return styleMap;
}

//or fancier

function simpleStyles(node) {
  return Array.prototype.reduce.call(window.getComputedStyle(node), function(map, prop, _, style) {
    map[prop] = style.getPropertyValue(prop);
    return map;
  }, {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getComputedStyle` in Chrome enumerates property names. Some CSS properties have aliases, so accessing the alias through either an array or hash within the same structure provides the best of both worlds.

Use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` to normalize the values across browsers:

```js
    var foo = getComputedStyle(document.body);
    
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo), function(key, value){ if (/[0-9]+/.test(key)) return undefined; else return value; }) )
```

**References**

- [ECMAScript Wiki:JSON Support](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=es3.1:json_support)
- [MDN:JSON.parse Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Examples)
- [Unified Diff: Source/build/scripts/make_css_property_names.py](https://codereview.chromium.org/1106443002/patch/40001/50003)
- [Documents | Firefox Site Compatibility](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/)